# use .so file by cpp and opencv project in java project

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

i add opencv library in c++ project and add java library in java project 
but when add .so file to java project

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
#include "OpencvCpp.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_OpencvCpp_myFirsttest
        (JNIEnv *, jobject){

//int main() {

    Mat img, img2;

    string filename = "/home/mohsen/Desktop/1.jpg";
    img = imread(filename);
    float m;
    for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 96; ++j) {
            m = m + img.at<uchar>(i, j);
        }

    }
    cout << m;
    return m;
}
```

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "jni.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
/* Header for class OpencvCpp */

#ifndef _Included_OpencvCpp
#define _Included_OpencvCpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     OpencvCpp
 * Method:    myFirsttest
 * Signature: ()F
 */
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_OpencvCpp_myFirsttest
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

when i run c++ project , return a good result
when get .so file and use in java project , show this error :

undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi

Comment: Just a guess but depending on the operating system you might need to add the location of the .so file to the PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  You also might need to add -Djava.library.path=... on the command to run java.

Comment: my os is ubuntu
how to sey path of library?
i add library of java opencv to my project by intellij idea !

Comment: I think you can edit the .profile file in your home directory to put export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/somedir  and logout and back in to change it outside intellij or within intellij  goto run -> edit configurations  and put -Djava.library.path=/somdir in VM options or click the environment variables thing to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH /somdir.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your library is using another shared library `.so` with opencv2 code.

In this case, you have to make sure it is visible to your JVM. The reason here is that once you "leave" JVM and you are inside your `.so` all depending libs are resolved by system, not JVM.

Take a look here for a sample where `.so` created for JNI is based on yet another `.so`.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

Have fun with JNI! :)

**Update**

To set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` use following

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: i am can not add so file to ubuntu .
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/"
error: /usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib/ not found

Comment: It looks like you have space in your export, also, it's good to wrap LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}